# how to search maven artifact using mojo?

Tags: maven, mojo, artifact

I'm wring mojo to download artifact from repo (Nexus). But most of the time I know only artifact Id , and version. Is there any way to download artifact only using  artifact Id and group id?

Answer (score 0):

The first things which is comming into my mind? Why don't you using the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) furthermore is does not make sense to download an artifact only based on groupId and artifactId, cause in Maven an artifact is identified by groupId, artifactId **and** version otherwise it's not unique. Otherwise it would be possible to use the REST API of nexus to a search for a list of artifacts.